# How to deploy web services in Apache Karaf using Metro framework?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-metro-framework, apache-karaf

I did a lot of research regarding this subject but couldn't get any information. I have a web project developed with Metro framework. It is not OSGi compliant and I am trying to work at it in order to deploy the application in Apache Karaf.

The information I found makes me think that only CXF framework is compliant with Apache Karaf but this is just a thought.

So, is it possible to use Metro in Apache Karaf? If so what are the steps to get it to work?

Comment: Right there with you. I already have a client JAR created against my Metro WS, and am using that successfully from within Camel.  But when I try to deploy my Camel route to Karaf I get a dependency exception:


missing requirement [237.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.ws)